# gdalbuildvrt: vrt output file must be in same directory

Tags: gdal

[gdalbuildvrt](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html)

For gdalbuildvrt it appears that from the docs (and my testing) that one must output the vrt file to the same directory that one calls the command in. Is this correct? And if so, what are the best ways to get around this if I am calling this command in a script?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is incorrect. I have tested all the types of calls using relative paths for the gdalbuilvrt and all the calls succeed.

Even this one works:

```
.\bin\gdalbuilvrt \export\result.vrt \data\tiff\*.tif
```

Check that all dependencies are available. The GDAL dll should be in the path or in the same directory as the gdalbuildvrt executable.
You could also use the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check that all the DLL dependencies are available.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I don't know what happened when I was working last week.